# Effect of location of MPI_Init on the speed of serial code

Tags: mpi, slurm

I have a code on cluster which is managed by SLURM. The code consists of   serial and parallel functions. Serial functions are called right after main and then parallel functions follow. I realized that when I initialize MPI at the beginning, right after main, the code slows down enormously for serial functions. But initializing MPI right before parallel functions and only after serials finish makes the code run at normal speed. I tried several options of SLURM as follows but they do not change the result. What I thought was if there are 5 nodes and 5 tasks then the speed should be more or less the same for serial functions. I would like to know why this happens.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);   

    int rank, n_procs;
    MPI_Comm world = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    MPI_Comm_rank (world, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size (world, &n_procs);

    // serial functions
    // parallel functions
}
```

Script 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -M truba 
#SBATCH -p mid1
#SBATCH -A a
#SBATCH -J a-test
#SBATCH -N 5
#SBATCH -t 3:00:0
#SBATCH --output=slurm-%j.out
#SBATCH --error=slurm-%j.err

module load centos6.4/lib/openmpi/1.8.8-gcc-5.1.0

mpirun ./out
exit
```

Script 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -M truba 
#SBATCH -p mid1
#SBATCH -A a
#SBATCH -J a-test
#SBATCH -N 5
#SBATCH -n 5
#SBATCH -c 16
#SBATCH -t 3:00:0
#SBATCH --output=slurm-%j.out
#SBATCH --error=slurm-%j.err

module load centos6.4/lib/openmpi/1.8.8-gcc-5.1.0

mpirun ./out
exit
```

Comment: What do the serial functions do? Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Can you quantify _enormously_? How did you measure it? Technically you should not execute code with side-effects before `MPI_Init`, because processes are not guaranteed to exist before that. However, I think in OpenMPI the processes will always exist before `MPI_Init`.

Comment: Could that be related to process pinning? In many cases, the process-to-core(s) attachment (if any) is done during the `MPI_Init()`. Maybe (complete speculation here) the attachment (again, if any) comes in the way of you "serial" code. Maybe this "serial" code uses some multi-threaded library (BLAS from MKL for example) which benefits from not having all threads bound to a single core...

Comment: @Gilles, binding in Open MPI is performed by the Open RTE launcher (`orterun` a.k.a. `mpiexec`/`mpirun`) or by the user-level daemon (`orted`), not during `MPI_Init()`.

Comment: @zulan: To quantify first node computes in 20 secs and 5th node computes in 1 hour for the very same serial code. From first to 5th node it takes more time to finish function. This increasingly more time consuming behavior happens for all functions consistently.

Comment: Pinning is the most likely suspect here. Your "serial" code must be using threads.

Comment: This is all guessing until you provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the serial code.